# How to use the wallpaper of an android phone as a background for an empty activity?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I need to write a program that gets the current wallpaper of an android device and to use it as  background for an empty activity. I am new to android programming so a detailed instructions would be use full.

Answer (score 0):

Get wallpaper and set background drawable

```
   WallpaperManager wallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
   Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Set id to your main rootlayout
ex your rootlayout id is llRoot than

```
llRoot.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

Comment: How to set wallpaperDrawable  as background for an activity?           Thank You